# TYPO3 ViewHelper is not laded

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, viewhelper

I am trying to write my own ViewHelper for TYPO3 Fluid

I have the file here:typo3conf/ext/ff_invest/Classes/ViewHelpers/LoremIpsumViewHelper.php

In this file  I have this code:

```
<?php
namespace Originalen\FfInvest\ViewHelpers;
/**
 * This class is a demo view helper for the Fluid templating engine.
 *
 * @package TYPO3
 * @subpackage Fluid
 * @version
 */
class LoremIpsumViewHelper extends Tx_Fluid_Core_ViewHelper_AbstractViewHelper {

/**
 * Renders some classic dummy content: Lorem Ipsum...
 *
 * @param int $length The number of characters of the dummy content
 * @validate $length IntegerValidator
 * @return string dummy content, cropped after the given number of characters
 * @author Lorem Ipsum <lorem@example.com>
 */
public function render($length) {
    $dummyContent = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
    return substr($dummyContent, 0, $length);
}
}
```

In my template file List.html I have

```
{namespace blog=Originalen\FfInvest\ViewHelpers}
```

in the top of the file and

```
<blog:LoremIpsum length="5" />
```

in the f.section part.

But I keep getting this error "Could not analyse class: "Originalen\FfInvest\ViewHelpers\LoremIpsumViewHelper" maybe not loaded or no autoloader".

I guess there is a misspelling somewhere. But I can't find it.

The namespace is the same as in the other files of the extension.

Comment: Code looks good on first view. You have cleared the TYPO3 cache?

Comment: Yes, and I just did it again, cleared the Cache in the Install-tool.

Comment: Now I get this error: Fatal error: Class 'Originalen\FfInvest\ViewHelpers\Tx_Fluid_Core_ViewHelper_AbstractViewHelper' not found in /var/www/www.domain.dk/www/typo3conf/ext/ff_invest/Classes/ViewHelpers/LoremIpsumViewHelper.php on line 10

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using? Do you use a custom `ext_autoload.php` in your templates root dir?

Comment: TYPO3 7.6.2
I don't think I use af custom ext_autoload.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your viewhelper class to use namespaces to extend core classes:

```
class LoremIpsumViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 7.6 puts the autoload cache into ´typo3temp/autoload/´ - so after deleting this folder new classes are recognized.

btw: the extension typo3_console provides a CLI command to do the same:

```
./typo3cms extension:dumpautoload
```